# How can I only display values that has the same column value laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a jobs table
[image]

focus on the schoolname column, what I want is that, I can only display all the values with the same column name, for example, I only want to display all the jobs that are related to dlsu@edu.org.

dlsu@edu.org is also the value for `Auth::user()->name`,

I have a blade in which it displays all the jobs, 
controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $jobs = job::all();
    return view('home',compact('jobs'));
}
```

blade:

```
<div class='col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2'>
    <center><h1>Jobs</h1></center>
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach ($jobs as $job)
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <a href="{{'/home/'.$job->id}}">
    <b>{{$job->jobposition}}</b></a>
    <span class="pull-right">{{$job->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</span>
    <p>{{$job->jobdesc}}</p>

</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to display all the jobs that are created by the same person `Auth::user()->name`

I am new to this and I know this is an easy thing, so please forgive me and thank you for answering

Comment: use where() condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$jobs = job::where('schoolname', Auth::user()->name)->all();
```